# Span Tag line-through Not Working in CKEditor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ckeditor

In my application I am using Ckeditor, and if I give a string to Ckeditor from the database, the span tag is not working properly.  Following is the code from database to Ckeditor:

```
<p><span style="color:red"><span style="text-decoration: line-through;background-color: rgb(129, 247, 243);">Demo for line Strike</span></span><span style="color:red">Demo</span></p>
```

My expected result in the picture below:
[image: Picture!]
and my result is:
[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are aware of this problem, As this ticket show similar error:

https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8118

If you use `<strike>` rather than line-through it seems to work.